# Arguments type conversion if a function is K&R-style defined

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Even if a function is defined in the K&R style, I expect that the type conversion for the arguments should happen. However, the output from the test program is:

```
int 9.42
int 2.97005e-12
flt 9.42
flt 9.42
```

It seems that the int value isn't converted to double. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double mult_pi_usual(double v) {
  return v * 3.14;
}

double mult_pi_KR(v)
double v;
{
  return v * 3.14;
}

int main() {
  printf("int %g\n", mult_pi_usual(3));
  printf("int %g\n", mult_pi_KR(3));
  printf("flt %g\n", mult_pi_usual(3.));
  printf("flt %g\n", mult_pi_KR(3.));
}
```

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: i586-alt-linux-gcc (GCC) 5.3.1 20151207 (ALT Linux 5.3.1-alt3)

Comment: FWIW, the same results apply to gcc 6.2.1 on Fedora 25. Both functions have identical assembly representation, but, as OP stated, the argument to multi_pi_KR() is not passed as a double. It's passed in the EDI register and EAX/rax is set to 0 (i.e. no FP arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a declaration, the K&R style does not convey type information for checking at the call point.

Consider the fact that a K&R function declaration (e.g. in a header) would be

```
double mult_pi_KR();
```

and the `double v` is only visible within the function definition.

For consistency across compilation units (not all will have visibility of the complete function definition), the type of the argument is not checked when calling the function.

In your example, this means the compiler - at points where the function in CALLED - does not know that `mult_pi_KR()` accepts a `double`.   So `mult_pi_KR(3)` does not promote `3` to `double`.

The result of passing an `int` to a function expecting a `double` is actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: So, the compiler intentionally ignores the type annotation. The explanation is reasonable, but my mind rebels against it. Is this behavior described somewhere in the specification?

Comment: @olpa - this might help you understand why the K&R form was deprecated in the first C standard, and a new means of declaring functions was introduced.   Early (pre-standard) versions of C were not designed with type safety in mind - that came later.

Comment: Using information that's not in the function definition would mean that the compiler would generate different code if the calling function was moved to a different file.

Comment: @stark - correct, except that you needed to use the word *declaration*, not *definition*.      [It's a bit murky, as formally a function definition is a type of function declaration, but not all function declarations are definitions.   A so-called function "prototype" is a declaration, but not a definition.].

Answer (score 1):

From the C89/C90 standard (6.3.2.2):

> If the function is defined with a type that does not include a
>   prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not
>   compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior
>   is undefined.

When you are passing the value `3` to a `double` parameter in `mult_pi_KR(3)`, an undefined behaviour is invoked and somehow, the value getting stored inside `v` comes to be `0.000000`. Nothing can be said about this value this is an undefined behaviour. Since `0` is never precisely stored in floating-point representation, multiplying it with `3.14` gives strange a value like `2.97005e-12`.

I have tried the same example but changed the type of `v` to `int` in `mult_pi_KR`. Then, the first call to `mult_pi_KR` works just fine, but due to the type mismatch in the second call to it, the value `1` is getting stored in `v`. Again, a value due to undefined behaviour.